# How many lines can a hypersurface contain before containing their span?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Suppose $X$ is the zero locus of a degree $d$ polynomial $f$ in $n$ variables over a field of characteristic 0. Fix an $m < n$ dimensional plane $H$ in $k^n$ and suppose that for some nonsingular $x \in X$, $X$ contains lines $\ell_1, \dots, \ell_N$ in $H$ passing through $x$.

How big can $N$ be before $X$ contains $H$? Arbitrarily large? Or is there some bound in terms of $n$ and $d$?

Comment: For a (dehomogenized) Fermat hypersurface, $X=\text{Zero}(t_1^r + t_2^r +\dots+t_n^r - 1)$, the point $(t_1,t_2\dots,t_n)=(1,0,\dots,0)$ is a smooth point, yet the hyperplane section $Y=\text{Zero}(t_1-1,t_1^r+t_2^r + \dots +t_n^r-1)$ is a cone.  For $n\geq 4$, this cone contains infinitely many lines through the point, even though the span of those lines is not contained in $X$.

Comment: In some contexts, such "cone points" are called "Eckardt points".

Comment: Ah, thanks! Are there some further assumptions that can be placed on the point x (beyond just being smooth) in order to get such a bound?

Comment: I just checked, and those points are called "star points" (nothing to do with me!).  For cubic hypersurfaces, star points are the same as Eckardt points, but in general they may be different.

Comment: Hm, can you have points of this sort other than star points? I.e., might you have a smooth point through which infinitely many lines pass but the intersection of the tangent space with the variety is not a cone (admittedly I don't really know what is meant by a cone)?

Comment: And one more question: Say X contains M smooth points, no 3 colinear and also the line spanning any 2 is contained in X. Is there some bound we can put on M or no?

Comment: @JasonStarr: out of curiosity, what is the general definition of "Eckardt point" that you are distinguishing from "star point"?

Comment: @Bertie.  I believe that an Eckardt point is a point $x$ where every tangent line to $X$ at $x$ has intersection multiplicity at least $3$ with $X$ at $x$.  For a degree $d$ hypersurface, I believe that a star point is a point $x$ where every tangent line has intersection multiplicity at least $d$ with $X$ at $x$.